# Can we do email tracking when sending email via smtp using php zend framework

Tags: php, email, smtp, tracking, mailgun

Currently I'm using mailgun to send email, but planing to send email using smtp in zend framework php.

My main concern are:

1. Need to track the emails against open and click by recipients.
2. how can we send the emails in batch like for marketing emails or bulk emails?
3. is there any limit like only x numbers of emails can be sent using one Smtp authenticated configuration?
4. do we need to have user based SMTP settings to send email from those users or is it possible to have one common SMTP settings base same email domain for all the users to sent email from our application?

Answer (score 0):

1. Mailgun have functionality for track your messages, more information you can find [here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#tracking-messages). If you want to have your own mail server for sending your emails I don't have idea how to track messages unfortunately
2. I think best way to send bulk email messages is queue implementation. You can implement own queue or use [something ready](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.queue.example.html). Mails should be send by cron job to avoid blocking main connecting thread
3. Yes, mailgun has limits: [Mailgun Pricing Page](https://www.mailgun.com/pricing) but if you wan't to send mails by your own server there are no limits.
4. You can have one account to send emails, it's not a problem

Comment: using one account to send emails not working as gmail override the actual sender by sender of that account.